# Javascript - How to pass original object to callback function

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, functional-programming

The problem I am having is specifically with D3.js, but I've had similar problems before and always ended up using a hack to get around it.

I have a class which contains an array of objects. There is a function to add new objects from a CSV file. using `d3.csv`. This function takes a filename and a callback function with one argument (the current parsed line of the csv file). I want to append each parsed line to `this.objects`, but `this` is no longer within the scope of the function.

```
function MyClass(){
    this.objects = [];
    this.add_objects = function(filename){
        d3.csv(filename, function(data){
             //Callback fired for each parsed line in csv file

             //Now I want to push data to this.objects...

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `var self = this;` in the beginning of MyClass and then use `self.objects`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common way to do this in javascript is with a closure variable in the parent scope:

```
function MyClass(){
    var self = this;
    this.objects = [];
    this.add_objects = function(filename){
        d3.csv(filename, function(data){
             //Callback fired for each parsed line in csv file

             // you can access self here
             self.objects.push(xxx);
        });
    }
}
```

or that variable could be more specific:

```
function MyClass(){
    this.objects = [];
    var objectArray = this.objects;
    this.add_objects = function(filename){
        d3.csv(filename, function(data){
             //Callback fired for each parsed line in csv file

             // you can access objectArray here
             objectArray.push(xxx);
        });
    }
}
```

or, you can use `.bind()` (if you don't need to support older IE like IE8) to create a wrapper that will force the setting of `this` for your callback:

```
function MyClass(){
    this.objects = [];
    this.add_objects = function(filename){
        d3.csv(filename, function(data){
             //Callback fired for each parsed line in csv file
             this.objects.push(xxx);
        }.bind(this));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach (but more complicated) is to use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
function MyClass(){
    this.objects = [];
    function handler(data) {        
        // here this is your binded this.
    }
    this.add_objects = function(filename){
        d3.csv(filename, handler.bind(this));
    }
}
```